# Pass a function through React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to pass a function to a child component through React Router. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="content">
          <div className="centered-wrapper">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
              <Route path="/life" render={props => <Life sayHello = {this.sayHello()} />} />
            </Switch>
          </div>                
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I wanted to call `sayHello()` in the Life component as follows:

```
<div className="hello">{ this.props.sayHello() } I'm <Link to="/life">Marco</Link>! Welcome to my hood.</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace:

```
<Route path="/life" render={props => <Life sayHello = {this.sayHello()} />} />
```

with

```
<Route path="/life" render={props => <Life sayHello = {this.sayHello} />} />
```

The mistake props receive the result of call of `sayHello()` function instead of function itself.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the function, you're calling it and passing the returned result as prop.

```
sayHello    // function object
sayHello()  // function call, evaluates to return
```

Remove the parenthesis:

```
render={props => <Life sayHello={this.sayHello} />}
```

In the future, take a look at any errors you see in the console and add them to your question. If you attempted to call `sayHello` in the `Life` component, surely you saw an error similar to this one:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

With this information, you could've found the problem yourself, or made it clearer for anyone trying to help :)