# How to pass an auth between react components

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble with passing a auth between react components.

What I want is display true when user click in the button Login. How can I do that? I want stay with Logout component at the App component in order to display in every page.

Sharing my code here: https://repl.it/@GustavoMonti/loginlogout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 steps to follow, plenty of stack overflow topics about each steps.

a) set a state hook on the App.js

b) then pass a method to change the state

c) pass methods through the Router - Another core topic [Pass a function through React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116467/pass-a-function-through-react-router)

Well discussed topic

d) call the method

Logout is not implemented you can do the same apporach and change the state in app.js to false passing the method

```
const App = () => {
//set the state
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const changeLogStatus = () => {
    setIsLogged(true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        Hi you are Logged? {isLogged ? "true" : "false"}
        <Routes changeStatus={changeLogStatus} />
      </div>
      <div>

        <Logout isLogged={isLogged} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

export default function Routes(props) {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
// see how the method is passed through the router , very important!
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={propss => (
            <Login history={history} changeFn={props.changeStatus} />
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}


// then call the method to change the state in the app.js
const Login = props => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setAuth(true);
    props.changeFn();   // calling the method
    props.history.push("/dashboard");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button className="btn" type="submit">
          Enter
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a value throughout a session in react there are several approaches that you can follow.

1. **Use `react-global-configuration`  :**

`npm install react-global-configuration`

then in your Login component:

```
import config from 'react-global-configuration';
config.set({auth: 'true'})
```

Then use it in any other component as

```
config.get('auth')
```

2. **Use LocalStorage**

   `localStorage.setItem('auth','true')
    localStorage.getItem('auth')`
3. **Use react-router history**

In login

```
this.props.history.push({
            pathname: '/Home',
            state: {
              auth: 'true'
            }
          });
```

and in Home component:

```
var myAuth = this.props.location.state.auth
```